# how to create a calculation on a dynamically added table row using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

hi i have a form which dynamically adds a table row from a external php file when a user clicks on the add button so far everything is working fine but i have field names'Qty' which will take input in numeric and should calculate the total of it i have created a calculation function but its working only for the first row can anybody help in how it should be done
here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#detail').on('keyup', '.qty', calculateRow());
                $('#addnew').click(function(){

                    var ctr = $('#items').val();
                    ctr++;

                    $.post('job_srch.php', {ctr : ctr}, function(data) {
                          $(data).appendTo('#detail');

                          $('#items').val(ctr);                        
                    });
                });

function calculateSum() {

    var sum = 0;
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".qty").each(function (){
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#total").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}

function calculateRow() {
    $('.qty').keyup(function () {
        //alert("entered");
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
        var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());

        calculateSum();
    });
}
   });
```

here is my php

```
session_start();
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
include ('includes/function.php');

$zdb = $_SESSION["zdbyear"];
mysql_select_db($zdb);

if ($_REQUEST["ctr"]){
    $ctr = $_REQUEST["ctr"];
    //echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chosen.css" />';
echo '<tr>

   <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="srno_'.$ctr.'" class="form-input-oth"/></td>
   <td align="center"><select data-placeholder="Party" style="width:300px;" name="item_'.$ctr.'" class="chzn-select-deselect" >
                                  <option value=""></option>';
                      $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items`") or die(mysql_error());
                      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
                             echo "<option value='$row[accode]'>$row[name]</option>";
                      }
    echo '</select></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><input type="text" id="qty" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_'.$ctr.'" class="qty form-input-amt"/></td>

                      </tr>';
}
else{
    echo "ERROR";
}
```

here is my html

```
           <table id="detail" border="1px" width="80%">
          <tr>
             <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
             <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">item</font><span></span></label></td>
             <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Quantity</font><span></span></label></td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="ord_0" class="form-input-oth"/></td>
                  <td align="center"><select data-placeholder="Party" style="width:300px; text-align: left;" name="item_0" class="chzn-select-deselect" >
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <?php
                                $iqry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `items` ") or die(mysql_error());
                                    while($trow= mysql_fetch_array($iqry)){
                                        echo "<option value=$trow[accode]>$trow[name]</option>";
                                    }
                          ?>
                      </select></td>
                  <td align="center"><input id="qty" type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_0" class="qty form-input-amt" onkeyup="return calculateSum(); "/></td>
              </tr>
<input type="button" id="addnew" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
                          <input type="text" id="items" name="items" value=" 0" />
```

Comment: I think you should use `.live` for this.

Comment: yup i did and it worked but can u help me with my first question coz the variable created in javascript doesnt seems to work

Comment: ok what is the problem I mean did the calcRow work when you do keyup on any '.qty'? and where you want to calc the sum of each row?

Answer (score 0):

change `$('#detail').on('keyup', '.qty', calculateRow());` `as`

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.qty', function(){
calculateRow(); // or code here
});
```